# 应用文翻译成什么比较合适 ？ Practical writing?

Tags: translation, writing

应用文（借用[百度的定义](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%BA%94%E7%94%A8%E6%96%87/4053193)）这种文体，英语到底翻译成什么？

关于“应用文”的概念，学界尚无统一严格的定义，也不可能会有这样的定义，不同的学者和书籍往往有不同的归纳和概括。学习者可从以下几个方面把握其本质特征：

1. 写作目的明确（实用性)
2. 语言表达规范（规范性）
3. 格式体例稳定
4. 时间要素明确

Google 查了半天，只查到 practical writing 感觉有点怪，很Chinglish的感觉

Answer (score 1):

据我所知，以及刚问了身边的同事。的确应该是practical writing。你是哪里觉得奇怪？

Comment: 其实这个问题前两天，我已经在另外一个SO另外一个地方问道答案了，但为了不让大家先入为主，我没说，你要是感兴趣就看看这里 https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/598366/practical-writing-or-is-there-a-name-for-this-type-of-essay

Comment: ”你是哪里觉得奇怪“ ，因为母语是英语的人不会这么说

Comment: 我在这里又问了一遍，是想知道还有没有别的说法。

Comment: @Qiulang邱朗 是的我同事给我的回答是，他印象里的确没有类似的概念，不像汉语把信件，报告，文书之类的实用的文章归纳为“应用文”这个类。大多数的应用文可能都会被称为Report。不过如果说到“应用文”这个总类别，他觉得practical writing 是正确的。他也觉得别人会懂。我在澳大利亚。这个可能只代表部分澳大利亚人的观点。

Comment: 难道这个答复不是让你意识到我得到回答才是比较标准的说法吗？ lol

Answer (score 1):

`Practical writing` is OK, for more accurate expression, I think `Practical document writing` or `Practical paper writing` is better, since according to the scope of `应用文`, it covers letter, announcement, conference record, instruction, etc. Most of these writings aim to official businesses. So to be more specific, I think you'd better add the word like `file`, `document` or `paper` explicitly in the middle of the phrase.

Comment: 美亚的产品确实这么翻译，比如 https://www.amazon.com/Practical-Document-Writing-Revisd-Chinese/dp/7563918701  但我真的觉得很 Chinglish

Comment: I think Chinglish may not be a bad thing as thought, English language has millions of words, part of which were from abroad such as vikings, indians, latins. `Long time no see` is typical Chinese grammar but has already accepted widely, not to mention  `Kongfu`, `Tofu`, 'Mahjong'.

Comment: "as bad as it sounds" not "a bad thing as thought"

Comment: correct, that sounds better

Comment: 如果你想练习英语，多试试 https://english.stackexchange.com/ 和 https://ell.stackexchange.com/  我不太建议在这里